# CakePHP: Show value stored in another model based on primary key

Tags: php, cakephp, primary-key, cakephp-model

Getting started with CakePHP and loving it. However I'm stuck in this noob situation and I'm not sure which way to solve this.

Basically, I have two models, departures and ports. The tables look like this:

**departures**

- id
- port_from
- port_to
- time_arrival
- time_departure

**ports**

- id
- name
- location
- active
- note

Now I want to list all the departures, port_from and port_to contains ID from ports. **Instead of showing just the port ID, I want to show the port name instead, but I have no idea how this could be done?**

Using two sets of $this->set in my Departures controller, I have the possibility to show values from the Ports table. *I have been looking for solutions but I don't think belongsTo or hasMany is the way to go here?*

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set relationship in your model:

```
class Departure extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'From' => array(
            'className' => 'Port',
            'foreignKey' => 'port_from'
        ),
        'To' => array(
            'className' => 'Port',
            'foreignKey' => 'port_to'
        )
    ) ;
} ;
```

Then you just use `find` or `read` to get your departure (in your controller):

```
$this->set('departure', $this->Departure->read(null, $id)) ;
```

And in view, you access ports name using:

```
$departure['From']['name'] ;
$departure['To']['name'] ;
```

And you access normal `Departure` info using:

```
$departure['Departure']['time_arrival'] ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You and @ADmad just saved me a huge amount of time and headaches! This worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can set two belongsTo associations in `Departure` model.

```
$belongsTo = array(
    'PortForm' => array(
        'className' => 'Port',
        'foreignKey' => 'port_from'
    ),
    'PortTo' => array(
        'className' => 'Port',
        'foreignKey' => 'port_to'
    ),
);
```

Now when you do a find() on `Departure` model in the results array, for each `Departure` record you will have the corresponding `PortFrom` and `PortTo` records.